# How do I get the main function from leetcode?

Tags: c++

I'm new to this website, Leetcode. While solving problems in C++, how can I get the main() function such that I can import these problems into my local IDE for solving and debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I use [Competitive Companion](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/competitive-companion/). Super useful, with support from a bunch of editors, though you'll need to install a plugin both in your browser and your IDE.

Comment: This allows you to see the main() function in C++? I use the leetcode extension is visual studio code, but that doesn't allow me to see the main still.

Comment: you don't have access to the `main()` function. The best you can do (and what the IDE portion of this extension does) is generate a `main()` function specific to your problem that simply pipes in the given inputs to compare to the given outputs. It is different from the leetcode extension. Here's the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DivyanshuAgrawal.competitive-programming-helper) to the vscode plugin.